# Adding the name of the corresponding file to the plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new in Python (and in programming at all) and trying to build the program for `.csv` data analysis.
I have multiple `.csv` files and for each of them I build a plot.
How do I add the name of the corresponding file to the title of the plot?
Thanks!

Below is the coresponding part of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

for fName in glob.glob('*.csv'): 
    df, loops = openF(fName)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

    for i in range(loops):
        df.loc[df['loop']==i+1][['freq','phase']].plot(x='freq', y='phase', logx=True, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title('Phase/Freq'.format(fName))
    ax.set_xlabel('Frequency, [Hz]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Phase, [rad]')



plt.show()
```

Comment: You forgot `{}` in `.format`. But you could write `ax.set_title('Phase/Freq %s'fName)` for instance or simply `ax.set_title('Phase/Freq ' + fName)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, David Leon, it works now!!!
:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it almost right.

In order for `format` method to work, you have to show it where to put the fName.
So you have to change

`ax.set_title('Phase/Freq'.format(fName))`

to

`ax.set_title('Phase/Freq {}'.format(fName))`.

here is full documentation about `format`:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Also if you are happy enough to be using python3.6 you can use f-string
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/